# How to install lxd 2.9 in ubuntu 16.04.2?

Tags: ubuntu, version, lxd

https://linuxcontainers.org/lxd/news/ says the latest version of lxd is 2.9.1, as of 16th February 2017.

I just installed ubuntu 16.04.2 and did

```
sudo apt install lxd
```

And I have

```
$ lxc --version
2.0.9
```

How do I update to 2.9.1?

Answer (score 0):

To get the latest upstream release, a PPA is available:

```
add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-lxc/lxd-stable
apt-get update
apt-get dist-upgrade
apt-get install lxd
```

(Arrogantly copied from the [docs](https://linuxcontainers.org/lxd/getting-started-cli/))

Answer (score 0):

The one way that I know is to first uninstall lxd then reinstall it using snap:

Here is the steps:

```
sudo apt remove lxd lxd-client
sudo snap install lxd
```

Then you can proceed with the configuration part:

```
lxd init
```

But what I am trying to find out if there is any way at all that I can upgrade it without uninstalling...